# Bootstrap btn-group change color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I change the background color of the active/selected button in the button group?

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic radio toggle button group">
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio1" checked>
  <label id="monthly" class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio1">Button 1</label>
        
  <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="btnradio" id="btnradio2">
  <label class="btn btn-outline-primary" for="btnradio2">Button 2</label>
</div>
```

By using this css, the unselected btn color gets changed. But how can I change the background color of the selected btn?

```
.btn-group .btn {
 color: #ff60bd;
 border-color: #ff60bd;
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in your css file and try.
First is to hide the radio controls, but second is I think what you need if you want to change the background color when button is **:checked**

```
input[type="radio"]{
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + .btn {
    color: #fff;
    background: #ff60bd!important;
}

input[type="radio"]:hover + .btn {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I added the code to my CSS and the selected btn's background color changed.

But now however, when i hover/press over the unselected btn, the standard background color appears again. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The selected or active button has active class, you need to check ".active" class of ".btn" as following sample:

```
.btn-group .btn.active {
 color: #ff60bd;
 border-color: #ff60bd;
}
```